# how to setup openVPN client proxy using PAC (proxy auto-config file)?

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn, pac, vpn-client

I am using an openVPN client to connect to a VPN. But the network that I am currently in sits behind a proxy and it manages proxy via PAC files (Proxy Auto-Config files).

I am looking at https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http to see how to connect to VPN behind a HTTP Proxy but the `http-proxy` takes a dns name /ip address and port and optional credentials.

Example: http-proxy 192.168.4.1 1080

It does not take a PAC file. How can I setup my openVPN client to accept/use PAC proxy file?

Comment: You probably can't directly.  What you may have to do is write some kind of script that downloads the pac, parses out the proxy, and then modifies your config and starts the VPN.  The tricky part is that a PAC is really a hunk of javascript code so parsing it out may not be easy.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a VPN using NetworkManager Applet version 1.8.20 (nm-applet). It seems to have provisions for importing a PAC script.